# Android Bottom Sheet after state changed

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a screen with a bottomsheet, but for the transition, and animation to work between activities I need the bottomsheet to be collapsed when the user goes on back pressed. I tried this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (mBottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    mShowingBack = false;
}
```

However, that doesn't work as the activity goes back while the bottomsheet is only halfway down.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED doesn't hide all the BottomSheet, it just sets the height of the view to whatever you set with setPeekHeight() or behavior_peekHeight in the xml :) but putting that aside... you should call super.onBackPressed() inside a BottomSheetBehaviorCallback when the state of the BottomSheet is STATE_COLLAPSED, like this:

```
BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(mBottomSheetBehavior);  
behavior.addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetCallback() {  
   @Override  
   public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {  
     if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED && mIsCollapsedFromBackPress){
        mIsCollapsedFromBackPress = false;
        super.onBackPressed();
     }
   }  

  @Override  
  public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {  
     // React to dragging events  
  }  
});
```

and your backPressed() method should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    mIsCollapsedFromBackPress = true;
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
}
```

Comment: the problem is, is that the bottom sheet gets collapsed for reasons other than changing activity, and i dont want the activity to change every time the bottom sheet gets collopsed

Comment: Well, in that case, maybe you can use a local boolean like... "mIsCollapsedOnBackPressed" and make it true in the onBackPressed, then make it false inside the BottomSheetBehavior "if"... that's the fastest solution I can think.

Comment: I just edited the answer, I think it should work for your case :)

Comment: thanks that worked,  I actually did something a little different (but inspired by your answer) that also worked, not sure which answer is better, i make the callback in the onbackpressed so it doesnt exist unless back button is pressed

Comment: how i can get state , like i want to see is full view displayed or users need to scroll up . so that i can show more info button in bottom if more data is present then current view

Comment: behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(); is depecrated

Answer (score 5):

```
behavior.setBottomSheetCallback();
```

Is now deprecated. Use this one instead.

```
BottomSheetBehavior.from(nearbyBottomSheet).addBottomSheetCallback(object :BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {

        }

        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
                
        }
})
```